# Поиск картинок в гугле

Tags: php, google-api

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
//парс картинок от гугла
$slovo = '123';
$slovo = iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $slovo);
$json = file_get_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&rsz=3&imgsz=medium&q='.urlencode($slovo).'&start=0'); 
$massiv = json_decode($json);

echo $massiv->responseData->results[0]->unescapedUrl;//первая найденная картинка
```

Собственно по справке гугла - 'должно работать', но не работает. Иногда возвращает пустой результат по доному и тому же запросу (паузу между запросами делаю 2-3 минуты). Может кто подсказать где ошибка, или так ли происходит обращение к api-google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file_get_contents` - убедитесь в конфигурации php, что [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/ru/filesystem.configuration.php)=1

сделайте `var_dump($massiv)` - убедитесь, что структура ответа верная

ну и наконец проверьте кодировку отправляемого текста. Если вы используете `urlencode`, то `iconv` вам ни к чему

Comment: Ответ крайне интересный, на все случаи жизни так сказать. В моем случае - убрал изменение кодировки и все заработало